# Is the integral closure the ring of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{F}_q(X)$ and let $L/K$ be finite. Let $\mathscr{O}_L$ be the ring of integers of $L$. For any $a\in K^* \setminus \mathbb{F}_q^*$, let $\mathscr{O}_a$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{F}_q[a]$  in $L$. What is the relationship between $\mathscr{O}_L$ and $\mathscr{O}_a$? If $a\in\mathscr{O}_L$, then $\mathscr{O}_a\subset\mathscr{O}_L$, but are they equal? What if $a\not\in\mathscr{O}_L$?

Any solution or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just saying you're looking at the ring of integers for an intermediate field, i.e. $K\subseteq\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_a)\subseteq L$. Just as in the number ring case, you can have proper inclusions across the board quite easily. Take $L= K(\sqrt[4]{x})$ which has degree $4$, and consider $a=\sqrt{x}$ clearly contained in $K(\sqrt{x})$. If $a$ is integral over $K$ it has to be in $\mathcal{O}_L$ since the latter is integrally closed, but not much else can be said as $a=x$ for example can achieve proper containment. Conversely if $a$ is not integral over $K$ then $\mathcal{O}_a$ cannot be contained in $\mathcal{O}_L$ because, for example, $a\not\in\mathcal{O}_L$, and also $\mathcal{O}_L$ is not necessarily contained in $\mathcal{O}_a$ as can be seen when $a=x^{-1}$ and $L=K(\sqrt{x})$ so that $\sqrt{x}\in\mathcal{O}_L$ is clearly not in $\Bbb F_q[x^{-1}]$.